# What is the friction between cylinder and wall (ground)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

A hollow cylinder (radius $R$) is rolling against the wall at angular speed $\omega$. The coefficient of friction between the cylinder and the wall(ground) is $\mu$. After how many rotations the cylinder will stop rotating?

So I figured I need to find the time taken for cylinder to stop moving, and that would be
$$
\beta=-\omega/t => t = -\omega/\beta
$$
Where $\beta$ is angular acceleration, which is known from torques:
$$
2*F_f*R = I*\beta
$$
That's where I got stuck... How do I know the friction? I'm familiar with such equation:
$$
F_f = \mu*F_n
$$
How do I find the normal force? Does it have anything to do with centripetal force?

Comment: The first thing to point is that the friction force at the wall and at the ground are generally not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at the following diagram, and then solve the equations:

[image]

Or just notice that $F_w$ and $F_f$ do not depend on $\omega$, then use the [Work-Energy principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28physics%29#Work-energy_principle).

> **Solution:**
>
>  $$\theta = \frac{R \omega^2 \left( 1+ \mu^2\right)}{2 g \mu (1+\mu)}$$

**step by step solution:**

> Horizontal forces:$$F_f-N_w=0$$
>
>  Vertical forces: $$F_w+N_f-mg=0$$
>  
>  We also know: $$F_f=\mu N_f$$ and $$F_w=\mu N_w \\$$
>
>  Solving them we find:
>  $$ \\ F_f=\frac{mg\mu}{1+\mu^2} \\ F_w=\frac{mg\mu^2}{1+\mu^2} \\ \Rightarrow \left(F_f+F_w \right)R \theta = \frac{1}{2}I \omega^2 \\ \Rightarrow \theta = \frac{R \omega^2 \left( 1+ \mu^2\right)}{2 g \mu (1+\mu)} $$

Comment: So as I understand F_f will be equal to µ*m*g (right?), but how do you find F_w? Also, using the work-energy principle, do we find that (F_w+F_f)*α = (I*w^2)/2 ?

Comment: No(did you see the $F_w$ pointing up?), and no(there is an $R$ missing in your argument)!

Comment: We have some unknowns, and some relations between them. We have to solve the equations to find the unknowns. If it is still ambiguous, I may include the whole step by step solution in my answer; but that's not the point of "homework" questions.

Comment: I do, I do want to understand it!:) I got the part with the missing $R$, I just can't seem to find the relations with frictions...

Comment: A big big thanks! Turns out I forgot the basics...

Comment: @Rugilena No problem.